# What is the name of the piece in the ballroom scene in "The Favourite" (2018)?

Tags: classical-music, soundtrack, baroque

There is a piece of baroque music played during [the ballroom dance scene](https://variety.com/2018/film/news/favourite-dance-scene-rachel-weisz-joe-alwyn-1203085751/) of "The Favourite" (2018), which was not released on the official soundtrack. What is this piece?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by Haendel, who frequently re-used his material. One example is from the concerto for due cori #2 in F major, HWV 333, 5th movement "Allegro ma non troppo". Compare this on [Youtube](https://youtu.be/a4PpGj8gPOc?t=552).

Another use is in Ode for the Birthday of Queen Anne, [Let rolling streams](https://youtu.be/VQR7mquSzHk)